# Date comparison in XSLT using Java

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am using the below code snippet to fetch the current date in XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentDate">
    <xsl:variable name="datePattern">yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new($datePattern), java:java.util.Date.new())" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Requirement is, to check if `ShippedDate` attribute value is equal to today's date, then include `<Monitor>` element, else exclude.

```
<Order>
    <Monitors>
        <Monitor ShippedDate="2015-11-10T00:00:00-05:00"/>
        <Monitor ShippedDate="2015-12-03T00:00:00-05:00"/>
    </Monitors>
</Order>
```

Can somebody please help me with what function needs to be used to achieve this?

Comment: Please show an example of the XML, and the expected output of the comparison.

Comment: Input XML : <Order> <Monitors> <Monitor ShippedDate="2015-11-10T00:00:00-05:00" /> <Monitor ShippedDate="2015-12-03T00:00:00-05:00" /> </Monitors></Order> Requirement is, to check if ShippedDate is equal to today's date, then include <Monitor> element, else exclude.

Comment: I updated the question with the code from your comment. Please also add what the value of `$currentDate` is and what the output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

> Requirement is, to check if `ShippedDate` is equal to today's date, then
>   include `<Monitor>` element, else exclude.

I would suggest you do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0 (+EXSLT)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
extension-element-prefixes="date">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Monitors">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Monitor[substring(@ShippedDate, 1, 10) = substring(date:date(), 1, 10)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Test input:

```
<Order>
   <Monitors>
      <Monitor ShippedDate="2015-12-01T00:00:00-05:00"/>
      <Monitor ShippedDate="2015-12-02T00:00:00-05:00"/>
      <Monitor ShippedDate="2015-12-03T00:00:00-05:00"/>
   </Monitors>
</Order>
```

Result, when applied on December 2, 2015:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order>
   <Monitors>
      <Monitor ShippedDate="2015-12-02T00:00:00-05:00"/>
   </Monitors>
</Order>
```

**Note:**

1. This requires a processor that supports the EXSLT `date:date()` extension function (e.g. Xalan or Saxon 6.5);
2. Only the date component is compared. If you are running the transformation in a time zone that's different from the time zone used in the input, the result may be inaccurate. If you want to also consider the time zone, then there's more work to do.

---

### Added:

> As a continuation of this, if none of the ShippedDate satisfies
>   condition, then no output must be transformed by XSLT.

Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
extension-element-prefixes="date">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Order">
    <xsl:variable name="current" select="Monitors/Monitor[substring(@ShippedDate, 1, 10) = substring(date:date(), 1, 10)]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$current">
        <Order>
            <Monitors>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$current"/>
            </Monitors>
        </Order>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its enough to compare the date component and this worked.

Comment: As a continuation of this, if none of the ShippedDate satisfies condition, then no output must be transformed by XSLT. Meaning, <Order><Monitors></Monitors></Orders> should not be sent. How do I handle this. Please help..

Comment: @user3440451 See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you pleease tell me how I close this question??